# Log in en node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, login

soy nuevo programando en node.js y quería hacerles una consulta: yo tengo el siguiente log in (que funciona sin problema) pero no estoy seguro si es la forma mas recomendable de hacer las cosas ya que no se si esta realizando su trabajo de forma síncrona o asíncrona. Como se cuando está realizando eso de esa manera y cuando no? Muchas gracias

```
 app.post('/Acceso', function(req, res){
    var conDB=DB();
    var UsuarioReg=req.body.Usuario;
    var ContraReg=req.body.Contra;
    conDB.query('SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE Usuario = ? and Contra= ?',
        [UsuarioReg,ContraReg],
        function(err,rows){
            conDB.end();
        if(err)
        {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        if (!rows.length)
        {
            return res.send("Usuario y/o clave no valida");
        }
        else
        {
            console.log(rows);
            return res.send("Accedido con exito");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Cuando se usan callbacks como lo esta haciendo en este caso, es un uso asincronico como es recomendado hacerlo en nodejs, pero lo unico raro que veo es que la conexion a la base de datos se cierra de manera sincrona a la funcion que recibe la peticion, sugiero que ese cierre se haga cuando el query responda, otra cosa que veo es que cuando haya error debe devolverse una respuesta dentro del response

Comment: Lcop, acabo de editar la pregunta con un cambio en el codigo. La forma en como lo hice es a lo que te referias? Estas diciendo que lo que se recomienda es que sea asincronico en node.js? Por que? (Tengo la sensacion de que esta funcionando mas rapido :D )

Comment: Node js se basa en uso de un pool de threads para procesar las peticiones, si se usa de forma sincronica, el va a encolar peticiones, perdiendo su ventaja. cada funcion es una peticion, que va a ir al pool y si se deja funciones sincronicas el va a demorar el proceso de las peticiones que se encolen en el pool

Comment: AHHH, ya entiendo. Lo que estas diciendo es que al haber puesto el codigo como lo habia dejado inicialmente, va a esperar a que haga todo el procedimiento del inicio de la sesiom, haciendo que se encolen las peticiones. Entonces, al dejarlo como lo modifique ahora, hace una peticion y apenas la realiza cierra la conexion y manda su respuesta, haciendo que deje de ser de forma sincrona. No entendia que hacia directamente jajaaja. Muchisimas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero que nada si es un programa de verdad (osea no es para practica) te recomiendo que uses la librería passport.js http://passportjs.org/ para node, que se enacarga de los logins de una excelente manera.

De no ser éste el caso, la mejor forma de hacerlo es de manera asíncrona, porque??... pues simplemente porque node está preparado para realizar funciones asincronas, al hacerlas sincronicas pues estás perdiendo tiempo y demorando la acción ya que encolará las peticiones.

Por último, de la forma qué estas haciendo deberías encriptar tu password con la libreria crypto https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html antes de guardar en la db usando un hash para desencriptarlo luego, es un error muuuuy malo grabar password en texto plano. (tódo este proceso lo hace passport.js)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por el consejo!!! Originalmente mi problema era con eso de asincrono que me resolvieron en los comentarios, pasa que tampoco me habia dado cuenta que en la edicion vieja del codigo (si queres te la muestro) estaba cerrando de forma sincrona, pero eso ya lo acabo de resolver. Esto es un prototipo para un proyecto que voy a hacer, pero ahora estoy investigando como voy a hacer las cosas. Del tema passport sabia, pero eso lo voy a investigar mas adelante que ahora quiero aprender a hacer un par de cosas primero. Muchismas gracias nuevamente por el aporte!!

Comment: por nada pero por mas que no lo hagas con passport encripta tu password ya sea con crypto o busca otra forma pero no lo dejes en texto plano. saludos

Comment: Hola @Alexis Granja. Estuve investigando recien el tema de la encriptacion con crypto de la password. Para hacerlo que me recomendarias que use?? SHA-512 o SHA-3 considerando que hago la base de datos en mysql y todo lo demas?? Saludos

Comment: Yo uso sha-512 depende de vos no mas conozco gente que usa sha-3

Comment: ah, bueno esta bien. Trate de usarlo y no me funciono...debe haber sido por un error tonto. Me podrias ayudar a descubrir que es?? Esta en ingles pero cualquier cosa te doy una mano con la traduccion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41774242/how-do-i-create-a-hmac-sha512-hash-using-node-js-and-crypto

Answer (score 0):

> No se si está realizando su trabajo de forma síncrona o asíncrona. ¿Cómo puedo saber cuando un proceso de ejecuta de forma asíncrona o no?

En teoría, si una función usa callbacks, es una función asíncrona. Si una función retorna un valor, es síncrona.

> No estoy seguro si es la forma mas recomendable de hacer el login

Es la forma estándar que la mayoría de aplicaciones utilizan: una petición a la base de datos y se crea un objeto en sesión almacenando los datos del usuario y  opcionalmente, se crea una cookie que almacene el token de sesión.

Existen diversas librerías para [Node.js](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tagged/nodejs) que te permiten automatizar en gran medida este proceso. Una de las más conocidas y usadas es [PassportJS](http://passportjs.org) pero también puedes hacer una atenticación basada en tokens como es el caso de [JWT](https://jwt.io/introduction/).

#### Usando estrategia local

Es realmente sencillo. Lo único que tienes que hacer son dos cosas:

1. Añadir un tipo de estrategia
2. Crear un middleware para usarla

En caso quieras una estrategia *local*, es decir, autenticación simple y directa, solo necesitas instalar el paquete [`passport-local`](https://npmjs.com/package/passport-local), instanciarlo y pasarle una función que será la que haya la autenticación.

**UserRepository.js**

```
export default class UserRepository {
  login (username, password) {
    const salt = Bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
    let hash = Bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      User
       .findOne({ username, password: hash })
       .then((user) => {
         resolve(user);
       });
    }
  }
}
```

**Authentication.js**

```
passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy((username, password, done) => {
    UserRepository
      .login(username, password)
      .then((user) => {
        done(null, user);
      });
  });
);
```

Por último necesitas añadir passport a tu ruta de login.

```
app.post('login', passport.authenticate('login', {
  successRedirect: '/home',
  failureRedirect: '/login',
  failureFlash: 'Usuario o contraseña incorrecta'
});
```

#### Usando estrategia JWT

Este tipo de estategia te permite autenticar vía JWT. JWT es un estándar abierto para la comunicación segura basado en JSON ([RFC7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519)). Este estándar usa distintos algoritmos para firmar la información a contenedir, que puede ser [`HMAC`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) o [`RSA`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA). Puedes ver información con más detalle sobre JWT [aquí](https://jwt.io/introduction/)

```
let options = {
  // extrae la cabecera HTTP 'Authorization'
  opts.jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader(),
  // secreto con el cual se crea el token
  opts.secretOrKey: 'secret'
}

passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(token, done) {
    // intenta decodificar el token. Si tiene éxito
    // devuelve true
    try {
      let decoded = jwt.verify(token);
      done(null, true);
    } catch (e) { // caso contrario, false
      done(e, false);
    }
}));
```

Ahora, puedes poner esta autenticación en un middleware para las rutas que desees. Cuando el token haya expirado o no sea válido, rediriges hacia una página en concreto, por ejemplo login.

```
router
  .get('/home', passport.authenticate('jwt', {
    failureRedirect: '/login'
  })
  ... otras rutas
```

Comment: gracias @Guz por la respuesta. En un momento voy a empezar a investigar lo de passport porque estuve ocupado con otras cosas. Mi idea en realidad va a ser iniciar sesión con facebook o google asi que voy a tener que investigar como autenticar con eso. Pero gracias por el aporte!

Comment: También puedes autenticar con Google, Twitter, Facebook y más con PassportJS.

Comment: Entra a la web de PassportJS y en el menú *Strategies* encontrarás muchas estrategias de autenticación. Hay muchas, por ejemplo para [Google](http://bit.ly/2kwXSPy), [Facebook](http://bit.ly/29NFYGC), [Twitter](http://bit.ly/2kEzw8Z), [Steam](http://bit.ly/2l5dH2Y), [Instagram](http://bit.ly/2khKP3e), [Linkedin](http://bit.ly/2kU6wZ8) y muchas más.